# Ruby on Rails net http response for ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to return a net http response from a link to remote call; however, I am unsure how to access information returned in the body.

This is what I have so far:

```
def get_info
uri = URI.parse("somesite")
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
render :json => {:name => response.body}
end

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#get_info').bind("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    alert(data.name);
});
});
```

This just dumps the xml returned to the pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do any kind of fancy stuff with the response I recommend using [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/):

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)
```

Then you can get e.g. the title with just:

```
title = doc.at_css('title').text
#=> "Title of the page"
```

Comment: Okay, how would I get an attribute of an xml element?

Comment: `doc = Nokogiri::XML(response.body) ; doc.at_xpath('//element')`, where "element" would be the name of the element. If you want the text of that element, you'd use: `doc.at_xpath('//element').text`. For details see: http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html

Comment: I found the following on here that worked: result = doc.xpath("//row").attr("name").text